# Wrap every word in a span tag concisely

Tags: javascript, anonymous-function

I'm trying to create an inline/copy-pastable anonymous function I can plug into my browser console to wrap every word in a page inside a span element.

Here's what I've tried:

```
(function() {
    document.querySelectorAll("*").each(function() {
        var text = this.text();
        var words = text.split(' ');
        this.innerHTML = '';
      
        for(let word of words) {
          this.innerHTML = word.replace(/(\w+)/g, "<span>$1</span>");
        }
    })
})();
```

Is there some way to get this to work?

Answer (score 0):

I test it for P tags and it works. I don't recommend run it for all elements :|

```
(function() {
  var elements = document.querySelectorAll("p");
  try {
    for (i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
      var text = elements[i].innerHTML;
      var words = text.split(' ');
      elements[i].innerHTML = '';
      for (let word of words) {
        elements[i].innerHTML += word.replace(/(\w+)/g, "<span>$1</span>");
      }
    }
  } catch {}
})();
```